# Rails 4, views wont render (ActionView::Template::Error (private method `send')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm stuck, im getting the weirdest errors in my rails application.
All views are crashing, not even the welcome#index (the default Rails page) renders.

I installed Rails, if tried different versions.
Updated my ruby to 2.1.2
Almost removed all gems from my Gemfile

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-14 11:13:40 +0200
Processing by Rails::WelcomeController#index as HTML
Rendered /Users/jos/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb (6.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms

ActionView::Template::Error (private method `send' called for #<#<Class:0x007fad0fa7e630>:0x007fad0b1d3070>):
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block in render_template'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:62:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `render_template'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
...
...
...
```

this is the content of my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',             group: :doc

gem 'spring',                       group: :development
gem 'mongoid', '~> 4.0.0.beta1'

gem 'devise'
gem 'doorkeeper' 

gem 'bcrypt' 
gem 'byebug'
```

Comment: Why do you think, that the error is coming due to *Gemfile* ?

Comment: i don't think the Gemfile is the error, maybe one of the gems was the source of the error, so tried different things ...

Answer (score 0):

**Dependencies**

If *all* your views are messed up, the problem is likely with another part of your system; typically one of the dependencies, or a part of the `rack` application

You already suspect this, as you've removed any `gems` which could be causing the issue. However, as this has not worked, I would look at these steps:

> 1. Try removing all the parts of your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` except for `<%= yield %>`
> 2. If you have any "non-rails" initializers, try putting them into recycle bin for now (restore later)
> 3. Try using the standard `WEBrick` server (default for rails)
> 4. Try removing `brcrypt` & `byebug` gems
> 5. Try removing any extra settings in your `config/application.rb`, `config/environments/development.rb` & `config/environments/production.rb` files

The core problem is that when you load a `view` in your application, the system has to load a lot of different files, many of which are not seen by the standard developer.

Whilst I don't think you have a problem with those, I *do* think there will be an issue with something else on the system (typically with the settings, gems or some other dependency you may have)

--

The process I would use is to literally get rid of anything which could prevent the app from loading; which will hopefully yield the issue that you can then solve